# Ubuntu Server with Broadcom 43xx WiFi

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

i would like to use my old Compaq Laptop as an server but using my WiFi to connect to my router

Therefor i tried to install Ubuntu Server 18/20/21 version and all work fine
and using the b43_installer the card is working and can be used (via NetworkManager i can see and connect to the WiFi of my router)
but i am not able to configure Netplan to make it run on startup

Using the Ubuntu Desktop (20/21) is an option, as there the 3rd party drivers are installed
but the computer is overloaded with the GUI and so not suitable for the task

so my question is, how to make the br43 driver work on startup or how to add the firmware to the ubuntu server live image, so i can configure the connection during install

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for it to work at startup

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175843/541617

the part of `echo "wl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`

Comment: thanks, it worked, unfortunatly the WiFi is dropping its connection after a certain time (adding an USB WiFi dongle solved the problem)